# Extract the strings in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-split

I'm new to regular expressions.

I got strings like:

```
DFE2001 NE Not 1
CAT11004 TP
FFE2001 NE Not 3
AVI2002 NE
LAB4000 SU
BA-PRI008 Not 1
FDD2001 NE Not 2
```

I need to extract the few strings which contain `Not x` by excluding `Not x`, that means, the output strings should be like:

```
  DFE2001 NE
  CAT11004 TP
  FFE2001 NE
  AVI2002 NE
  LAB4000 SU
  BA-PRI008
  FDD2001 NE
```

Can any one please tell me the regular expression and the function on how to use for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
preg_replace('/\s*Not \d\s*$/', '', $string)
```

It will remove the "Not x" with surrounding spaces from the end of a string ( x means any numeric character).

Comment: Thanks @TareqMahmood: one line code. working like charm. thank you. Thanks everyone and SO.

Comment: its not removing the space before Not 1. can you please tell me on how to remove 1 space before Not 1

Comment: Did you check my latest edit in the answer? I guess you are still using the first one I wrote. Pls confirm.

Comment: this also working. preg_replace('/ Not \d$/', '', $mystring). thank you

Comment: Yes. Should work if you are sure there will be always one space.

Comment: Can you address this string too please.. $mystring = 'BA-PFB021 Nots 1, 6, 11 and 16 Not 1'; it should string from first Not.

Comment: Try this `/\s*Not[\d\s,\w]*$/`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your try guys, I've managed to do this using strpos and substr functions like:

```
$mystring = 'DFE2001 NE Not 1';
// $mystring = 'LAB4000 SU';
$findme   = ' Not';
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);

// Note our use of ===.  Simply == would not work as expected
// because the position of 'a' was the 0th (first) character.
if ($pos === false) {
    echo "The string '$findme' was not found in the string '$mystring'";
        $mystring = $mystring;
        echo '<br/>mystring::::' . $mystring;
} else {
    echo "The string '$findme' was found in the string '$mystring'";
    echo " and exists at position $pos";
        $mystring = substr($mystring, 0, $pos);
        echo '<br/>mystring::::' . $mystring;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note** :- This is just a sample code you have to make your own logic to calculate for whole given string.

```
$re = "/.+?(?= Not)/";      // reg to check string having Not
$str = "DFE2001 NE Not 1"; 
preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
echo '<pre>';print_r($matches);  // take out string before Not
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?:(?!\bNot\b).)*(?=\s+|$)
```

You can try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hE4jH0/44

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'^(?:(?!\bNot\b).)*(?=\s+|$)', re.MULTILINE)
test_str = u"DFE2001 NE Not 1\nCAT11004 TP\nFFE2001 NE Not 3\nAVI2002 NE\nLAB4000 SU\nBA-PRI008 Not 1\nFDD2001 NE Not 2"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as the number following `' Not '` is always one digit, you can do this using only `substr`.

```
$input = array('DFE2001 NE Not 1',
    'CAT11004 TP',
    'FFE2001 NE Not 3',
    'AVI2002 NE',
    'LAB4000 SU',
    'BA-PRI008 Not 1',
    'FDD2001 NE Not 2'
);

array_walk($input, function(&$x) {
    if (substr($x, -6, -1) == ' Not ') $x = substr($x, 0, -6);
});
```